# Compilation error with xlc++ and aix (The #include file <initializer_list> is not found)

Tags: c++, c++11, aix, xlc

I can't find the reason for this compilation error:

```
The #include file <initializer_list> is not found
```

I'm compiling with c++11 flag: qlanglvl=extended0x
The version of xlc++ is 16.1 in aix 7.2

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if that compiler supports all of C++11?

Comment: Yes, in theory, Initializer lists are supported from the version: started in 13.1

Comment: I don't know anything about your compiler, but perhaps it intends you to include `utility` instead?

Comment: Is the compiler able to find other headers, just not this one? It's possible that your installation is messed up a little bit or your include paths are not correct.

Comment: import <utility> works, but now I have another compilation error :(
Error: An initializer is not allowed here.  When I try to use std::initializer_list<int> as function parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of C++11 is implemented in xlC V16.1.  There is an xlclang++ compiler in V16.1 that supports all of C++11.